# Captcha with jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate, captcha

I'm using the famous [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and i want to implement the captcha control. On their [page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) in the demos section there's [that](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/captcha/) but it seems to has an issue: when you click the image to refresh, it doesn't refresh! It's a famous plugin, so I've not posted codes because are many php files, and maybe many of you already know the solution. If needed I will try to post them. Thanks

EDIT

**// index**

```
<?php

// Make the page validate
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '0');

// Include the random string file
require 'js/captcha/rand.php';

// Begin the session
session_start();

// Set the session contents
$_SESSION['captcha_id'] = $str;

?>
<form id="form">
             <div id="captchaimage">
                <a href="" id="refreshimg" title="Click to refresh image">
                    <img src="js/captcha/images/image.php?<?php echo time(); ?>" width="132" height="46" alt="Captcha image" />
                </a>
             </div>
             <label for="captcha">insert captcha:</label>
             <input type="text" maxlength="6" name="captcha" id="captcha" />
```

**// newsession.php**

```
<?php

// Include the random string file
require 'js/captcha/rand.php';

// Begin a new session
session_start();

// Set the session contents
$_SESSION['captcha_id'] = $str;

?>
```

**// process.php**

```
<?php

// Begin the session
session_start();

// To avoid case conflicts, make the input uppercase and check against the session value
// If it's correct, echo '1' as a string
if(strtoupper($_GET['captcha']) == $_SESSION['captcha_id'])
    echo 'true';
// Else echo '0' as a string
else
    echo 'false';

?>
```

**// rand.php**

```
<?php

// Create a random string, leaving out 'o' to avoid confusion with '0'
$char = strtoupper(substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz'), 0, 4));

// Concatenate the random string onto the random numbers
// The font 'Anorexia' doesn't have a character for '8', so the numbers will only go up to 7
// '0' is left out to avoid confusion with 'O'
$str = rand(1, 7) . rand(1, 7) . $char;

?>
```

**//Validation**

```
$("#form").validate({  
    rules: {

        'captcha':{
            required: true,
            remote: "js/captcha/process.php"
        }
    },

    messages: {
        'captcha': "error"  
    },

    onkeyup: false
});
```

**// script refresh captcha**

```
$(function(){
    $("#refreshimg").click(function(){
        $.post('js/captcha/newsession.php');
        $("#captchaimage").load('js/captcha/image_req.php');
        return false;
    });
});
```

**// image_req.php**

```
<?php

// Echo the image - timestamp appended to prevent caching
echo '<a href="" onclick="refreshimg(); return false;" title="Click to refresh image">
        <img src="js/captcha/images/image.php?' . time() . '" width="132" height="46" alt="Captcha image" />
      </a>';

?>
```

Comment: What is your issue? The fact that the sample on the demonstration doesn't work, or it doesn't work for you on your own site?

Comment: You can put link to this image. <a href=""></a> and it will refresh

Comment: @ben: it doesnt work on my own site in the same way it doesn't work the demo!

Comment: @croios: with your solution it refresh but regenerating the same image! and if I click again to refresh it reload the entire page!

Comment: I cannot see any element with id #refreshimg in posted code nor #captchaimage

Comment: now i've posted all the codes/script

Comment: With full code, i cannot point any problem here.

Comment: with those codes you will have the issue as on the demo: no refresh image and on the second click it reload the entire page. with the code in the deleted answer: the src correctly refresh but the image remains the same

Comment: this problem is certainly kafkaesque

Comment: no one can help me? the code is above and the demo doesn't work. there must be an issue...

Comment: And where is the rest of the relevant code?  I don't see the jQuery that contains `.validate()`.  Also, it seems you have to click twice to get the captcha to refresh in [the demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/captcha/index.php).

Comment: i've added the jQuery part of code with the .validate() but the validation works. now i've discovered a thing: if I use the link <a> (for refresh) on a button separated from the captcha image it refresh for each click but regenerating a new image with the same letters sequence

Comment: Since the demo seems to be flaky, my suggestion would be to use a different demo or captcha method.  I could provide a working example using "re-captcha" and jQuery Validate if you want.  Otherwise, it seems pointless to continue struggling with something that we can't even play around with here.

Comment: Sparky: Still extending that offer of reCAPTCHA and jQuery Validation example? I have a jQuery Validation rule written, but don't know what id to point it to...

Comment: Finally I found that implement the notorious and powerful [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) in jQuery Validate is better and more simple. Here is explained how: > http://coderpills.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/adding-recaptcha-validator-to-jquery-validate/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style>
.good {color: green;}
.bad {color: red;}
#captcha {
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
</style>
<?php
function background($length = 6) {
$characters = "ABCDEF0123456789";
$string = "#";
for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
$string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];}
return $string;
}
$f = background();
function signs($length = 6) {
$characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz";
$string = "";
for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
$string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];}
return $string;
}
$a = signs();
?>
<script>
$(function() {       //run when the document's ready, elements are loaded
$("#refresh").click(function() { 
$("#captcha").load(location.href + " #captcha");               
});
});   
</script>
<script>
$(function() {  
$("#send").click(function(evt) {
if ($('#check').val() === $('#verify').val()) {
$("#result").html("<h3 class='good'>Correct</h3>");
evt.preventDefault();
} else {
$("#result").html("<h3 class='bad'>Incorrect</h3>");
evt.preventDefault();
}
});
});   
</script>
<head>
<h1>Captcha all in one</h1>
<hr />
</head>
<body>
<div id="captcha" style="height: 50px; width: 125px; background-color: <?php echo        $f;   ?>"><font face="OCRB" style="font-size: xx-large;" color="<?php echo $a;  ?>">
<p id="secimage"><?php echo $a; ?></p></font><input type="text" id="check" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" style="display: none;"/></div>
<button id="refresh">&uarr;&darr;</button>
<input id="verify" type="text" placeholder="Enter code" />
<button id="send">Check</button>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As with third-party tools, it would be nice to provide a code sample. Also note that these answers are meant to survive for ages and still be useful. I'm afraid free file-sharing sites are _particularly_ likely to rot over time.